# Form element with sliders for X, Y axes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Is there an existing implementation of a form element which looks like

[image: A box with sliders for both axes]

Can this be made using jQuery UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/)

```
$( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "orientation", 'vertical' )
                .bind("slidechange", function(event, ui) {
                    // update y
                });
```

Then make one with default orientation and update x